# Creating jQuery-like animations in Dart 2 for a HTML element

Tags: jquery, dart, dart-html

How to create animation for a HTML element in Dart 2 that resembles jQuery `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`?

I saw this `animate` method in the `dart:html` package. However, it seems that it does not change the style of the element to the final state so after the animation is completed the element immediately turns back into the first state like before the animation was started. It is also stated by the documentation that calling `animate` will not only create an `Animation` class but also calling the `play()` method too so the animation is played automatically upon creation.

Does `animate` in the `dart:html` package use Web Animation so it does not change the style of the HTML element at all? If so, how can I persist the state of the element after the animation has completed? I can see that using jQuery `fadeIn` the opacity of the element changes from time to time from 0 to the final state which is 1. So after the animation has completed, the opacity of the element remains 1.

I hope I can avoid this:

```
elem.animate([{"opacity": 1}, {"opacity": 0}], 100); // animation is played immediately after this
elem.style.opacity = "0"; // force set the style to 0
elem.style.display = "none"; // also force set the display to none
```

Comment: Why not just applying the style yourself at the end of the animation?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that is what I wanted to do. The Animation object returned by the `animate` method seems to have `onFinish` method. Problem is, calling `animate` will autoplay the animation before I can set the onFinish handlers. I can set it while the animation is running by placing the onFinish immediately after animate but this seems to be quite a dirty hack. I am having a difficulty finding how to create Animation object without playing it automatically so I can set the onFinish handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart's animation API directly ports the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) so anything you can do with it, you can do in Dart in almost exactly the same way. With WAAPI, creating animations always involves two parts: specifying the keyframes (a.k.a. the effect) and then [timing parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EffectTiming) (or just the duration, if no specific timing effect is needed).

Among the timing parameters, there is one referred to as the [fill mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EffectTiming/fill) which affects how the element is rendered when the animation isn't actively running. To have the element remain in the state defined by the end of the animation after it has finished, all you need to do is set the `fill` parameter to `forwards`.

Just like with WAAPI in Javascript, in Dart, the animation timing parameters are set in the 2nd parameter of the animate method, with a Map in lieu of just a duration. This is also where you set things like delay, easing, and animation direction.

```
//Notice that this Dart code is entirely compatible with JS!
el.animate([{"opacity": 0}], {
  "duration": 1000,
  "fill": "forwards"
});
```

[Here's a working example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f1dbe7c64b6d20cfacbc763e112c5d16).

You can also construct animations on an element **before** you want it to run. The `.animate` method returns an [Animation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-html/Animation-class.html) object you can store and control the animation from. You can create it, call `.pause` on it immediately, and then play it later, among other things. This is all still in total parity with WAAPI.

```
Animation fadeOutEl = el.animate([{"opacity": 0}], {
  "duration": 1000,
  "fill": "forwards"
})..pause();
// Somewhere else 
fadeOutEl.play();
```

Dart's documentation of the animations API is definitely scant, but since it's effectively identical to WAAPI (and it's built on it, after all), all you need to do look at its docs on MDN, and from there, translating to Dart's implementation is pretty trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! Yes I was having difficulty in reading the documentation. Would you mind sharing some references to other ways to create Dart HTML animations? WAAPI seems to be still in working draft...

Comment: So, I was a tiny bit mistaken in regards to other ways of creating animations (it was late, gimme a break!). For now, your only options are WAAPI or applying CSS animations/transitions. It doesn't look like there are any good convenience libraries on pub for web animations either (but I'll add that to my list of future Dart projects). WAAPI browser support is problematic outside of Chrome, but maybe you can provide a [polyfill](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js)? If you try it out, let me know if you get it work.

Comment: I also added another example to my answer showing how to create WAAPI animations without playing them immediately.